# What is "SPOCK" exactly?

Tags: project-team

I cannot see the exact definition of the "SPOCK".

Is it something like a "Subject-Matter-Expert"? So a person, who is the max/top consultant from the given technical subject?

Comment: I agree with Danny, I bet you're looking for SPoC. Being that the case, would be nice if you could rephrase your question as it'll be more useful if mentions SPoC rather than Spock.

Comment: Firms might use the Spock term to use a nerd reference for CEO / CTO / or even Subject-Matter-Expert (if subject matter is seen as a starship) . Spock is a fictional character in the Star Trek media franchise. In latter moments he was the captain (not the highest rank), which means he was responsible to command a starship. One of his famous quotes -> «The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few, or the one.».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>If you really mean SPOCK then you are probably referring to the testing and specification framework for Java and Groovy applications by [SpockFramework.org](http://spockframework.org/)</sup>

> <sup>Spock is a testing and specification framework for Java and Groovy applications. What makes it stand out from the crowd is its beautiful and highly expressive specification language. Thanks to its JUnit runner, Spock is compatible with most IDEs, build tools, and continuous integration servers. Spock is inspired from JUnit, jMock, RSpec, Groovy, Scala, Vulcans, and other fascinating life forms.</sup>

---

But based on your question I suspect you are asking what a **SPOC** is.

SPOC is an abbreviation for "**S**ingle **P**oint **O**f **C**ontact".

This is a business term used to refer to a single person or team within a company who are designated as the point of contact for all incoming communications with a specific outside company.

Often the SPOC is an expert on the subject matter, so as to minimize the turnaround of the communication.

But often it's simply a way to ensure that all communication to and from the outside company is unified; if only one person is authorized to communicate with them, you will not have the problem of different people telling them different things.

For example:

If you have a SPOC with your outsourced graphics company, then only the SPOC is authorized to ask for graphics, ask for changes and answer questions the graphics company may have. Obviously the graphics company must be informed that only communication via the SPOC is authorized and binding.
If somebody else gets involved, they can be safely ignored by the graphics company.

In this case the SPOC does not need ot have any special graphics abilities; they could even by color blind - they would simply use internal channels and procedures to get approvals, suggestions, etc.

If you do not have a SPOC with the graphics company then every time anybody from the company asks them to change something, they may do so, creating havoc. The graphics company also has no idea who to get approval from, and to whom to send the final product.

Answer (score 1):

The word SPOCK has different meanings.
According to freedictionary.com, SPOCK is an American pediatrician, educator, and writer.
Spock can also be referred to as a testing and specification framework for Groovy and Java applications. Spock is compatible with most IDEs, build tools, and continuous integration servers. What makes Spock stand out from the crowd is its beautiful and highly expressive specification language.